# AppDynamics open source alternative?

Tags: gratis, java, monitoring, performance-analysis

Is there any [AppDynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppDynamics) open source alternative? I'm looking for something that at least:

1. would capture call trees along with time spent on each level allowing to pinpoint the problem
2. would work across servers/webservices in soa/microservice architecture - monitoring whole stack, not just single machine/service/jvm
3. would support metrics/charting/alerting (or would allow to export relevant data)

If not open, is there anything like that free as in beer? (free version of AppDynamics does not meet 2nd criteria )

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is quite what you are looking for, but [Warewolf ESB](http://warewolf.io) is gratis (no charge) and open-source. It also utilizes microservices to build applications - so presumably you could build the performance monitoring tool using it.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We prefer our recommendations to be full fledged personal recommendations that come from personal use. So, did you use Warewolf ESB? Did it work well? What are its drawbacks? If you didn't use it for the intend of the question, for what did you use it? Please be more verbose about this. Hope to see you around.